# Prove that there are no natural numbers $x$ whose digits are $0$ or $2$, such that $x$ is a perfect square.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are no natural numbers $x$ whose digits are $0$ or $2$, such that $x$ is a perfect square. I need some help here. I thought starting with $x = n * 10^k$ where $10^k$ represents the number of the zeros at the end of the number and $n$ is the group of digits which end with $2$ could help, but it didn't. Can anyone help?

Comment: It might be more fruitful to decompose $y = n \cdot 10^k$ such that $10$ does not divide $n$, where $x = y^2$.

Comment: The last non-zero digit of a perfect square is always 1, 4, 5, 6, or 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dividing by an appropriate power of $100$ we can ensure that the final two digits are not both $0$.  But a simple search (or congruence argument) shows that none of $2,20,22$ are squares $\pmod {100}$.